# Configuring a port with my local SSL certificate

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, ssl, x509certificate

I have generated my local SSL certificate using this link -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx

I have, my certificate, my pfx file and my pvk file.
I added the certificate to MMC under Local machines and Current Users Personal Certificates.

But after this I was unable to associate this certificate to any port on my machine using the netsh prompt. Every time I try to do this:

`http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8888 certhash=‎b9fa246fc12207570f19f93771b735b3b94aa816 appid='{<00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF>}'`

OR

`http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8888 certhash=‎b9fa246fc12207570f19f93771b735b3b94aa816 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}`

I get an error message = `The parameter is incorrect`

I am working on a Windows 8.1 machine and need this to host a WCF Soap Service on a wsHttpBinding endpoint with security Mode = "Transport" and ClientCredentialType= "Basic".

Any help on getting this certificate associated to a port would me much appreciated.

-Kunal

Comment: When I pasted your second sample there was an incorrect character just between `certhash=` and `b9fa...`

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, but even removing the special character did not help

Comment: Replace `'` with `"`

Answer (score 1):

We have noticed a similar issue in the past, when attempting to use a certificate that did not contain the private key.  You may want to verify that your certificate is properly imported and contains the private key.

In order to verify, open the certificate properties from the MMC certificate management console and make sure the key icon is shown along with the message "you have a private key that corresponds to this certificate". (image example below)

[image: certificate with private key]

Regards,

Comment: I have the private key to the certificate. I verified that.

Answer (score 1):

Try again with double quotes around the appid & certhash (if you copy-paste, remove the character that comes before the certhash string):

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8888 certhash="b9fa246fc12207570f19f93771b735b3b94aa816" appid="{00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}"
```

If this doesn't work, find out if your port isn't already bound:

```
netsh http show sslcert 0.0.0.0:8888
```

If so, remove it:

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8888
```

and then add it again.

If adding still doesn't work, then it might be your thumbprint that isn't right. Else, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I used `appid={....}` but when I surround it quotes like so `appid="{....}"` it works!